# Oracle 10g forms builder 'add item to cart' from table function/code

Tags: oracle10g, shopping-cart, oracleforms

I don't know how to implement add cart function in creating my ordering system using oracle 10g forms builder. I have a list of products in my table and I want to put a button beside each item which users can input how many they want to add in the cart, and display the total price that is included inside the cart. thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an unbound (non-database) text item (for the quantity) and a Button to the database block.

In the when-button-pressed trigger for the button, you can then evaluate the price x amount and add the selected item/count to your cart...

Comment: can I ask some example code sir? I don't know how to execute your solution :(

Comment: Example code for Oracle Forms is tricky as much of it is done through the GUI editor.  Assuming you have the database block built, you add a text item and a button to that block.  Then add a WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger to the button:
`begin
  :control.total := :products.n_item_count*:product.price;
end;`
This example is HIGHLY trivialized as it doesn't handle changing product counts within the cart, but should hopefully get you moving...